# When parsing text file input does not move to next line

Tags: java

I am looking for a little help.  I have done quite a bit of googling with little success.

I am new to programming and am sure this is a silly oversight on my part.

The below code is intended to read through a .txt document that is tab delimited.  The .txt file is formatted into six columns.  Currently, as I move through the file I parse the string to the appropriate value type and assign it to its respective variable.  Code is here:

```
        try {
            s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))).useDelimiter("\t");
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
              group = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
              death = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
              name = s.next();
              sex = s.next();
              age = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
              fare = Double.parseDouble(s.next());
              System.out.println("Class = " + group); // Test that value is being assigned
              System.out.println("Death = " + death); // Test that value is being assigned
              System.out.println("Name = " + name); // Test that value is being assigned
              System.out.println("Gender = " + sex); // Test that value is being assigned
              System.out.println("Age = " + age); // Test that value is being assigned
              System.out.println("Fare = " + fare); // Test that value is being assigned
           }
        } finally {
            if (s != null) {
               s.close();
            }
        }
```

When I reach the last column of the first row, the variable fare is set to row 1 column 6 AND row 2 column 1.  For some reason the line break is not triggering the while loop to restart.

Can anyone help me understand why the while loop does not restart at the end of the line?

File looks like this:

```
1     5     Bryan     male     25     211.3375       
1     2     Jimmy     male     22     151.5500
```

There is about 1200 lines of this.  When running this loop I get the below error when attempting to set fare = 211.3375 at the end of the first row.  For some reason, the line break isn't resetting the loop.  I can only assume that the line break is not interpreted as a tab but do not know how to correct this.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "211.3375
1"`

Comment: to be honest I would change your flow to do nextLine to read into a String and then do a String.split using the tabs char.  Obviously you are not reading the EOL char.

Comment: Why use `Integer#parseInt` or `Double#parseDouble` when the `Scanner` class has `nextInt` and `nextDouble`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're checking `Scanner#hasNextLine()` but then reading multiple `Scanner#next()`, a dangerous thing to do. I suggest if you check for next line, you should **read** next line, and then parse through that line.

e.g.,

```
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = s.nextLine();
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
    group = lineScanner.nextInt();
    death = lineScanner.nextInt();
    name = lineScanner.next();
    sex = lineScanner.next();
    age = lineScanner.nextInt();
    fare = lineScanner.nextDouble();
    lineScanner.close();
    System.out.println("Class = " + group); // Test that value is being assigned
    System.out.println("Death = " + death); // Test that value is being assigned
    System.out.println("Name = " + name); // Test that value is being assigned
    System.out.println("Gender = " + sex); // Test that value is being assigned
    System.out.println("Age = " + age); // Test that value is being assigned
    System.out.println("Fare = " + fare); // Test that value is being assigned
}
```

But even this is somewhat dangerous because I'm calling `Scanner#next...()` without first checking. And so perhaps safer would be to do

```
String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
```

Then count the tokens length to be sure that it's right, and then parse each individual token that needs parsing to numeric type.

Or you could do something like:

```
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = s.nextLine();
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);

    if (lineScanner.hasNextInt()) {
        group = lineScanner.nextInt();
    }
    if (lineScanner.hasNextInt()) {
        death = lineScanner.nextInt();
    }
    if (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
        name = lineScanner.next();
    }
    if (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
        sex = lineScanner.next();
    }
    if (lineScanner.hasNextInt()) {
        age = lineScanner.nextInt();
    }
    if (lineScanner.hasNextDouble()) {
        fare = lineScanner.nextDouble();
    }
    lineScanner.close();

    System.out.println("Class = " + group); // Test that value is being assigned
    System.out.println("Death = " + death); // Test that value is being assigned
    System.out.println("Name = " + name); // Test that value is being assigned
    System.out.println("Gender = " + sex); // Test that value is being assigned
    System.out.println("Age = " + age); // Test that value is being assigned
    System.out.println("Fare = " + fare); // Test that value is being assigned
}
```

or use try/catch blocks to check for bad files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of your input.  I made the modifications you suggested in the first code block.  For some reason I am now throwing an InputMismatchException.  I am trying to identify the reason, but am not having much success.

Comment: @Zeeboot: Always look critically at the exception stacktrace as it will tell you what is wrong. Also use a debugger to see the state of your variables as the code is running.

Comment: Thank you Hovercraft.  I will definitely try to do that.  I think my lack of experience will make that a bit difficult but worth a shot.